# How can I know when I am at the end of a string in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code something that can do the job of `.length` in Javascript. In others words, I'm trying to code a function that can count the caracters in a string.

Now, I coded something that stops when it detect an `" "`, but it's not the best thing because the user can't enter any space in his string. In C there is `\0` at the end of a string, how can we see it in Javascript?

```
function StringLength() {
    var nb = 0;
    var i = 0;
    //take the value of 'inputUser' and save it in 'input'
    var input = document.getElementById('inputUser').value;
    input = input + " ";
    //loop that stop when there is a " "
    while (input[i] != " ") {
        nb++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get that this is supposed to be a learning exercise but it doesn’t seem like a useful one. Why not count vowels or something? JavaScript strings aren’t C strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a property past the end of a string, the value will be `undefined`:

```js
function StringLength(str) {
    var i = 0;
    while (str[i] !== undefined) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
console.log(StringLength('foo'));
```

Comment: Think it's also important to note that strings are immutable and that doing `string[index] = undefined` will not change the string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `/n` at the end of the string in C. `/n` doesn't mean anything special, it is a `/` followed by an `n`.

You are probably thinking at `\n`, which is the [new line character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) but the C strings do not end with it.

The length of a C string is not stored anywhere. In order to compute it you have to rely on the fact that after the string there always is a [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (i.e. the character with code `0`) that is usually represented as `\0`, `\x0` or just `0` in C.
But this how C strings are defined. They always have a Null character after the string and the program can access any memory location it wants, including the Null character that is *after* the string data.

**Javascript is a different language, it uses different rules.**

First of all, the program cannot access random memory. It cannot check if there is a Null character after the string because it can get only the characters that are *inside* the string.
The Javascript interpreter knows what is *inside* and what is *outside* the string because it also stores the string length.

From the program's point of view, there is nothing outside the string and, if you want to reach a character outside the string (by using an invalid index) you get `undefined`.

You can use this to compute the length of a Javascript string:

```js
function StringLength(input) {
    var i = 0;
    while (input[i] !== undefined) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

// Examples of usage
console.log(StringLength(''));
console.log(StringLength('abc'));
```

Use the function in your code like this (get the value you want to measure outside the `StringLength()` function to make it reusable):

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputUser').value;
var length = StringLength(input);
```